# Hortonworks Hive Username password configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am attempting to get a connection to the hive server and keep getting:

```
HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [hue] does not have [CREATE] privilege on [default/testHiveDriverTable]
```

Not sure what username/password combination I should use.

I have Hortonworks running on a virtual machine. The code I am attempting to use to connect to the Hive server is:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(“jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.6:10000/default”, “hue”, “”);
```

I have also tried connecting via the "root", "Hadoop" username, password configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of the error message, the `Connection` is OK, but you lack privileges to execute the `Statement` just below... because that *"testHiveDriverTable"* label smells like you did a copy/paste on some dummy code example such as:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://10.0.2.15:10000/default", "", "");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
```

The *"no [CREATE] privilege on [default/testHiveDriverTable]"* message is a good fit for a **create table testHiveDriverTable** attempt in database **default**.

Bottom line: congratulations, you actually could connect to Hive. Now you can work on how to configure the "default" database so that you can actually create tables :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting without giving username and password? I have the following connection string on my cloudera virtualbox which works
Connection con = DriverManager.getconnection(jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default,"","");

Here default is the DB name.

Comment: Even with a blank username/password I get the authentication error 
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [anonymous] does not have [CREATE] privilege on [default/testHiveDriverTable]"